# Error parsing JSON string in Android

Tags: java, android, json

Having trouble parsing a JSON string in Android. The string itself looks fine, at least it looks like what I intended to be returned. But I'm crashing when trying to parse it. Can anyone see why? Thanks!

```
static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            if (params != null) {
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            }

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.e("JSON", json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            System.err.println("start try3"); //<--fine here
            System.err.println(json);         //<--json string looks good
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);     
            System.err.println("done try3");  //<--never outputs
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
```

Stack Trace:

> 08-05 15:28:00.665: E/JSON Parser(20009): Error parsing data
>   org.json.JSONException: Value
>   [{"id":"3","bool_gets_sms":"0","picture_url":"none","email":"heather@me.com","cell":"12345","name":"Heather"},{"id":"7","bool_gets_sms":"0","picture_url":"none","email":"alan@me.com","cell":"12335","name":"Alan"},{"id":"10","bool_gets_sms":"0","picture_url":"none","email":"jenni@me.com","cell":"12345","name":"Jenni"},{"id":"11","bool_gets_sms":"0","picture_url":"none","email":"jeff@me.com","cell":"12345","name":"Jeff"},{"id":"24","bool_gets_sms":"0","picture_url":"none","email":"rob@me.com","cell":"12345","name":"Rob"}]
>   of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're instantiating as a JSONObject, that is a JSONArray, change that datatype and constructor.

From your stack trace:

```
of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

So, instead of this:

```
static JSONObject jObj = null;
// ...
jObj = new JSONObject(json);
```

This:

```
static JSONArray jArr = null; //changed jObj to jArr for your naming conventions too...
// ...
jArr = new JSONArray(json);
```

You should know what type of data organization the server will return before making a request although you can find out programatically, it's better to know in advance. JSON is pretty simple and you can [read through the spec](http://www.json.org/) in minutes... TL;DR: Curly braces around text denotes an object, brackets denotes an array...

Comment: I can change what the server returns. Changing to a JSONArray is very problematic since it has many downstream consequences. Can you suggest what type of format the server should return to fit into the JSONObject class?

Comment: @usr55410 All you have to do is nest that array in an object. What language is your server running?

Comment: php. The last line in my php code is `echo json_encode($array);`. I have total flexibility to change that if it will fit into the JSONObject class more seamlessly.

Comment: @usr55410 Change that line to something along the lines of echo `json_encode(array("users" => $array));` Then it will be an object with the array nested with a tag of 'users'

Answer (score 0):

You should do it like that:

```
JsonElement el = new JsonParser().parse(json);
JSONObject obj= el.getAsJSONObject("the key you are looking for");
```

The exact name of the methods might differ depending on the library you use for JSON parsing.
Take care to get the arrays in a JSONArray instead of a JSONObject.